# Problems with getResultList()

Tags: hibernate

I am currently working on a performance tuning project based on Hibernate. I am however facing one issue in the below part of the code snippet which greatly reduces the performance. Below is the part of the code snippet:

```
private EntityManager em;
Query query = em.createQuery(sQuery.toString());
List<Object> entities = query. getResultList();
```

I did put timers on both the lines of code and i see that the query takes some 0.02 seconds to fetch lets say x number of rows (the same time it takes to run when run via a DB client). However, the most of the time is being taken by the second line, i.e. getting the list (getResultList()). I am beginning to think whether this is normal and by using getResultList actually makes the performance of the application down. Any Suggestions please?

Comment: The first line, `Query query = em.createQuery(sQuery.toString());`, is in fact not querying the database at all.  It is just parsing the query string and building a "query plan".  The second line is what talks to the database and "performs" the query.

Answer (score 0):

> 0.02 seconds to fetch lets say x number of rows (the same time it takes to run when run via a DB client)

Its not hibernate its the db call, and its not slow. 0.02 seconds to send data to database perform query and then send data back is fast, very fast.

**edit its four seconds**
Show the code for the sql query, optimize that. Then after doing that the only way to get it faster would be to cache the results on the java side.

I use [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What i mean to say is the second line, i.e. List<Object> entities = query. getResultList(); is the one taking long time. For fetching two records, although the query takes 0.02 secs, but the "query. getResultList()" takes 4 seconds to save to a list of objects. This is where my problem lies.

Comment: the code you posted is not saving anything anywhere. 4 seconds is quite long - I would guess the same query takes a long time from db client ? createQuery is not fetching any data.  It's a sql query, post that code.

Comment: I believe he means 4 seconds for reading the db result into memory and storing it into the list object. 
How are you measuring the time for the getResultList() method? Does it always take ~4 seconds? How much memory has your program at hand?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @NimChimpsky 0.02 is not that bad.

Anyhow, you can also try to use a NamedQuery which will be preprocessed by hibernate when the application starts and it will probably save you some time when executing it.

Comment: named queries are better than the posted code, but using one won't effect performance of getResultList. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2642031/106261